# Regular expression to capture value in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

In Jmeter, want to capture the POD's id from the below json response code. Tried $..result[*].id and its displaying all IDs including the onces from Value1, Value2. But my requirement is just to capture the PODID, so that it can be passed in next request.
Also is it possible to save the PODIDs in an array and send them in the next requests?

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "Value1": {
                "name": "Random1145843",
                "id": "32f338ffce"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "configuration": null,
            "timeZone": "America\/New_York",
            
            "Value2": {
                "name": "Random1137530",
                "id": "0940c7a8d7"
            },
            "ready": "ready",
            "organization": {
                "name": "Randome42711",
                "id": "da54c68830"
            },
            "name": "PodId_50631",
            "host": null,
            "id": "PODID_50631",
            "state": {
                 "mil": "clear",
                "diagnostic": "clear",
                            },
            "status": {
                "estimated_weight
                    "value": {
                        "uom": "KG,
                        "value": 500.0
                    }
                   
                },
               
           {
            "Value1": {
                "name": "Random1145443",
                "id": "32f3385fce"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "configuration": null,
            "timeZone": "America\/New_York",
            
            "Value2": {
                "name": "Random1137530",
                "id": "0940c758d7"
            },
            "ready": "ready",
            "organization": {
                "name": "Randome42755",
                "id": "da54c65630"
            },
            "name": "PodId_506356,
            "host": null,
            "id": "PODID_506356",
            "state": {
                 "mil": "clear",
                "diagnostic": "clear",
                            },
            "status": {
                "estimated_weight
                    "value": {
                        "uom": "KG,
                        "value": 500.0
                    }
                   
                },
                     {
            "Value1": {
                "name": "Random1145653",
                "id": "32f338f564"
            },
            "parent": null,
            "capabilities": null,
            "configuration": null,
            "timeZone": "America\/New_York",
            
            "Value2": {
                "name": "Random1135630",
                "id": "0940c734
            },
            "ready": "ready",
            "organization": {
                "name": "Randome42756
                "id": "da54c68830"
            },
            "name": "PodId_34556,
            "host": null,
            "id": "PODID_34556",
            "state": {
                 "mil": "clear",
                "diagnostic": "clear",
                            },
            "status": {
                "estimated_weight
                    "value": {
                        "uom": "KG,
                        "value": 500.0
                    }
                 
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `..` [operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) which means "deep scan" so it will return all `id` attributes values no matter where they're located.

You need to limit the extraction of `id` attributes to just direct children of the `result` [JSON array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp). Something like:

```
result.*.id
```

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-path-extractor-jmeter)